# Pandas merge column after json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dicts in a single column but for each row, a different *post_id* in a separate column. I've gotten the dataframe I am looking for via `pd.concat(json_normalize(d) for d in data['comments'])` but I'd like to add another column to this from the original dataframe to attach the original *post_id*.

**Original**

```
'post_id' 'comments'
 123456    [{'from':'Bob','present':True}, {'from':'Jon', 'present':False}]
```

**Current Result** (after `json_normalize`)

```
comments.from    comments.present
Bob              True
Jon              False
```

**Desired Result**

```
comments.from    comments.present    post_id
Bob              True                123456
Jon              False               123456
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider first outputting dataframe [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) then run [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import json
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = DataFrame({'post_id':123456,
                'comments': [{'from':'Bob','present':True}, 
                             {'from':'Jon', 'present':False}]})    
df_json = df.to_json(orient='records')

finaldf = json_normalize(json.loads(df_json), meta=['post_id'])    
print(finaldf)

#   comments.from comments.present  post_id
# 0           Bob             True   123456
# 1           Jon            False   123456
```

Comment: how would you normalize this if your json string was a list of jsons like
`[{'from':'Bob','present':True},{'from':'Bob2','present':True}]`

Comment: You might need to ask a new question. Normalization is not needed without nested elements.